# How to begin new transaction using ADO

Tags: vba, ms-access, transactions, ado

I've tried

```
CurrentProject.Connection.BeginTrans
'   This acts as if you didn't begin a transaction. 
'   Changes are posted real time then gets an error on Commit that you are not in a transaction
```

---

```
Private conn As ADODB.Connection 

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
conn.BeginTrans
'   This fails silently in the sense that nothing posts to the database when it gets committed
```

---

```
Set conn = New ADODB.connection
conn.Open GetConnectionString
conn.BeginTrans   
'   This fails on the first SQL statement with
'   "Object variable or with block variable not set"
'   But it clearly is set because it works if I don't start a transaction
```

---

```
'   You would think that starting a transaction explicitly would work.
Private conn As ADODB.Connection 

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
conn.Execute "Begin Transaction", , adCmdText Or adExecuteNoRecords
'   This also fails silently in the sense that nothing posts to the database when it gets committed.
```

Commit looks just as you would expect. Whichever of these is appropriate:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.CommitTrans
conn.CommitTrans
conn.Execute "Commit Transaction", , adCmdText Or adExecuteNoRecords
```

Nothing works.

I can easily get it to work on DAO.

```
DAO.Workspace.BeginTrans
```

works just as you would expect, except that only DAO statements are committed. Anything posted through ADO is lost, disappearing as if they didn't happen.
But I don't want to switch hundreds of SQL routines to use DAO if I can avoid it.

Note that I'm not trying to create a new connection to the back end. These are all linked tables, with Access compatible SQL statements.

The solution I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275312/commit-transaction-in-ms-access-fails-to-write-to-database), doesn't appear to be working after all.

What is the recommended approach to transactions in ADO on local tables?

Comment: for your second example, are you indeed calling `conn.CommitTrans`?

Comment: Where is the CommitTrans action? ADO code works for me.

Comment: 'fails on first SQL statement'. What statement? What error?

Comment: Question updated with clarification.

Comment: @June7  OK. That's interesting. I'll try a sample project and see if I can reproduce. Are you sure it is on local or linked tables, not a direct SQL connection?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'direct SQL connection'. Data is linked Access backend.  `Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection cn.BeginTrans` followed by conditional code that leads to cn.CommitTrans or cn.RollbackTrans.

Comment: @June7 Well, that's the local access tables all right. And exactly what I'm doing. We'll see what the sample project shows tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know. Everything works in the sample program. I thought the issue might be that we are running against Postgres instead of SQL Server, but it works fine with both. Back to the drawing board. Rollback works as well.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯